# VSTS - releasing environment-specific web.config

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a web.config.test & web.config.production checked into my project. These get built and released to an on-prem server. I think the Command Line task will work to copy the correct file as web.config but I can't figure out how to resolve to the path, as my build is zipped up. Something like

```
copy web.config.$(Release.EnvironmentName) web.config
```

but it fails not being able to find the specified file. I echo out the $(Release.EnvironmentName) and it writes "test" to the log, so that's the correct filename, but not sure what the path would be to the file inside the zip. Any ideas?

Comment: Update - I ended up including all environment-specific config files with the solution, then creating another "Publish Build Artifact" task copying them to the server. I then added a PowerShell release task to copy the environment-specific file to the actual file, e.g. "web.config.pre-production" copied to web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [extract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/extract-files) zip file, then copy files, after that you can [archive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/archive-files).